# Use jQuery to compare dynamic text input value against data attribute

Tags: jquery, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match, string-comparison

I have an input field that I'm using to compare against data attributes.  I'd like to use `regex` to compare the users input against the data attributes on `keyup`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="text-filter" placeholder="Search by Name">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 item" data-name="Clark Kent">
        <div class="mbs-item-inner">
            /* Content Goes Here */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 item" data-name="Peter Parker">
        <div class="mbs-item-inner">
            /* Content Goes Here */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 item" data-name="Bruce Wayne">
        <div class="mbs-item-inner">
            /* Content Goes Here */
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#text-filter').on('keyup', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        text_filter_value = $this.val().toLowerCase();

    $('.item').each(function(index, element) {
        var name =  $(this).data('name').toLowerCase();       


        /* This only displays an .item when there is an exact match
         * but I want every item that contains similar pattern matches to be displayed
         * 
         * In other words if a user starts typing 'Pe' 
         * then I want the 'data-name="Peter Parker" .item to be displayed
         * I'm assuming I need to use regex for this but I'm unsure as,
         * how I should implement it
         */        
        if(text_filter_value === name) {
            $(this).show('slow');
        } else if(text_filter_value === '') {
            // If text input is empty show all
            $(this).show('slow');
        } else {
            $(this).hide('slow');
        }

    });

});
```

Any help would be appreciated and please include working code examples if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are 2 ways of doing it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 item" data-name="Clark Kent">
        <div class="mbs-item-inner">
            /* Content Goes Here - Clark Kent */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 item" data-name="Peter Parker">
        <div class="mbs-item-inner">
            /* Content Goes Here - Peter Parker */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 item" data-name="Bruce Wayne">
        <div class="mbs-item-inner">
            /* Content Goes Here - Bruce Wayne*/
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Approach 1 : Looking for the exact match as you type. Using string comparison.

```
$('#text-filter').on('keyup', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        text_filter_value = $this.val().toLowerCase();

    $('.item').each(function(index, element) {
        var name =  $(this).data('name').toLowerCase();       

        var charLength = text_filter_value.length;
        if(name.substring(0,charLength).toLowerCase() ===       text_filter_value.substring(0,charLength).toLowerCase()) {
            $(this).show('slow');
        } else if(text_filter_value === '') {
            // If text input is empty show all
            $(this).show('slow');
        } else {
            $(this).hide('slow');
        }

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jdn283cj/1/

Approach 2 : Text found anywhere : Using indexOf()

```
$('#text-filter').on('keyup', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        text_filter_value = $this.val().toLowerCase();

    $('.item').each(function(index, element) {
        var name =  $(this).data('name').toLowerCase();       


        if(name.indexOf(text_filter_value) != -1) {
            $(this).show('slow');
        } else if(text_filter_value === '') {
            // If text input is empty show all
            $(this).show('slow');
        } else {
            $(this).hide('slow');
        }

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jdn283cj/

In both the examples, you don't need regex. Just simple js logic.

Comment: brilliant! Thanks so much for a great solution... clearly I was overthinking the problem. Cheers